# Troubles with floats and margins

Tags: html, css, css-float, margin

I'm having some troubles with floats and margins on my website, (given that I'm not the best coder in the world) I'm trying to define a width to a class and make it float left, and doing the same to another one trying it to float right but it's not seemed to be working. Anybody have any tips or can solve the problem?

The problem (scroll to the bottom) : http://baileyiglesias.co.nr/home

The CSS File : http://baileyiglesias.co.nr/library/css/mainstyle.css

Just to let you know I know there isn't a defined width on the footer. I just want it to be like the header so it just sticks to the sides.

Thanks

-Bailey

Comment: Which part of your website is the faulty part? Can you please add a sample of your HTML and relevant CSS to this question?

Comment: The very bottom, the footer where it says "copyright & cookies", I'm just about to add it to the question.

Comment: Remove the `width` from both `divs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
footer .colophon {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    padding: 0;
}

footer .copyright {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
```

Remove the widths, widths are automatically set by getting the width of the text.

Use float left on .copyright for aligning it next to the first div and right to get it to the right site, your choice:)

Comment: Ahh! You genius, Thanks a lot!(: